# Wordpress plugin installation fail

Tags: wordpress

While trying to install plugins in wordpress site, I get the following error

```
Unpacking the package…

Installing the plugin…

The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.

Plugin install failed.
```

Comment: In my experience this is not a fault of wordpress, but normally one of the following. No disk space on server, tmp folder on server is full, or other server related issues.

Comment: There is almost always another issue. If the server has been running for a long time, you might want to check the /var/log directory as well. Wordpress can spit out a lot of errors to these files.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the cPanel, try this:

1. Download the plugins that you want to install on WordPress.
2. Open your CPanel and sign in.
3. Open  “File Manager”
4. Locate your wordpress installation there and Click on the folder
   marked “wp-content”
5. Open the folder marked “plugins”
6. Click on “upload file(s)” and upload the plugin you just downloaded.
7. Click on the plugin file that you just uploaded and click “extract”.
8. Open WordPress and go to the dashboard.  Click on “Plugins”. ( You
   should see your new plugin as one of the selections. )
9. Click “Activate”.

The above steps are explained assuming your hosting is With HostGator. The steps are similar for other hostings also.

Cheers !!!

Comment: This really isn't a fix for the actual problem, its just another way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have put wrong folder/file.
wordpress only get realized that there is a plugin when it can get a php file which header contain at lease this line

/*
Plugin name: your plugin name
*/

So, you have to check..

- unzip the plugin file and see if there any php file containing header like that. you plugin file should be in.. wp-content/PLUGIN_DIRECTORY/PLUGIN_FILE.php

check this first and let us know if it works or not

Comment: Interesting that the page at https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin doesn't say a word about this.

Comment: Header requirements https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/

Answer (score 1):

One of my co-workers figured this out. 
Check your wp-config.php and look for these lines:

define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', '02775');
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', '0664');

Note that the values 02775 and 0664 are encased in quotes and so PHP interprets as strings. 
They are numeric values and should not be contained within quotes.